# DataFrame filtering

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame `df`, if one wanted to filter the DataFrame to rows that have `column_4` between 45 and 48, one might try the following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({f'column_{i}': range(i*10, 10*i+10) for i in range(10)})

df2 = df[45 < df['column_4'] < 48]
```

However, this code yields a ValueError, because `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` One instead must do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({f'column_{i}': range(i*10, 10*i+10) for i in range(10)})

df2 = df[(45 < df['column_4']) & (df['column_4'] < 48)]
```

Why is this the case - and is this a hacky way to filter a DataFrame?

This question has a seemingly partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o), however that does not seem to address specifically why `45 < a < 48` does not work.

Comment: Does not answer your question, but you can simplify your method here with: `df['column_4'].between(45, 48, inclusive=False)`

Comment: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) may help

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me in the right direction. Writing up the answer as a self-comment now.

Answer (score 0):

[It's already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283872/how-do-i-boolean-mask-an-array-using-chained-comparisons), I was just searching the wrong terms.

The short answer is that chained relational operators such as `1 < a < 4` are expanded internally as `(1 < a) and (a < 4)`. `and` and `or` cannot be overridden in Python -- see [PEP335](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) and [guido's post to the mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117510.html) -- which means numpy can't use chained relational operators as masks. Thus, neither can Pandas.